# How do I activate Dead Code Stripping when building for the iOS Simulator in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, linker, ios-simulator

I am using Xcode to build a project that links precompiled object files. These object files contain some unresolved symbols that are dead-code. When Xcode builds for the iOS Device, it strips them when linking and everything works smoothly. When building for the Simulator, however, it doesn't strip them (-dead_strip is not passed to the linker) even though the option (Dead Code Stripping) is activated in the project configuration. If I manually add -dead_strip to the link command on the terminal it builds and runs correctly in the simulator.

How do I make Xcode pass -dead_strip as argument to the linker when building for the iOS Simulator? I prefer a clean solution, hot a hack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this steps:

1) Open XCode and press cmd + 1

2) Click on your project at left panel -> your target at middle panel

3) Click on "Build Settings"

4) Find "Other Linker Flags" and add here a your own linker arguments

Hope will be a useful

Comment: While this did fix the problem, I'd still consider it a workaround rather than a clean solution. I am happy with half the bounty points.

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW8) it says that

> GCC_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = full is a prerequisite for
>   DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING.

Maybe that is set *incorrectly*?