# unused code in xcode project - app store update submission

Tags: ios, itunes

I'm submitting an update to my first application on the iTunes (update 1.1). I was wondering if it would be an issue if I left code in the project that went completely unused.

I have two examples:

- I will be doing localization in the update after this but I've
  already put in NSLocalizedString and the localizable.strings file.
  This really isn't necessary at this point until I get back
  translations and I submit 1.3. So currently it's just English.
- Next is I'm trying to add "log in with Facebook" to my application. It works perfectly when the user logs into Facebook with apple settings. Unfortunately, if they don't log in via apple settings and only directly in facebook application. when they select log in with facebook on my application I'm getting errors.. I'm still researching how to fix that (super frustrating) but my question is if I just disable/hide the button in my app will apple care that I have a method and hidden button that isn't called/used?

Should I comment out the unused code? or will apple not care that there are unused methods?

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't care about your code. You can submit it.

Comment: Well they don't care about the extra code. It would be nice to think they cared about the code to some extent :D

Comment: I don't see why they should care about how you write your software. Do you really want to send them code reviews before submitting the app? :)

Comment: I just meant the statement "Apple doesn't care about your code" made me laugh.

Comment: Thanks Sha and it is a pretty funny statement!

Answer (score 2):

They don't care about unused code, as long as you don't use anything that's from private API or so. You can go ahead and submit.

Answer (score 1):

It won't matter as long as your code isn't impacting the stuff that is working. In many cases the dead code won't even be compiled; if it really concerns you, can you force the compiler to perform [aggressive dead code stripping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646994/how-do-i-activate-dead-code-stripping-when-building-for-the-ios-simulator-in-xco).